# How to make a continuous beep on android

Tags: java, android, audio

So I am developing an app and I need to have a beep continuously being played without gaps when something occurs. The only thing that I have it's a beep with like 100ms period but it has gaps.

Answer (score 1):

```
 final ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,100);
                        handler.postDelayed(this,250);
                    }
                },100);
```

For to stop

```
handler.removeMessages(0);
```

Comment: I don't know if you tested it, but it doesn't make any sound

Comment: yes i have tested it i set this on button click and it sounds perfectible